# Pandas assign value to dataframe column based on two lists using one column of the dataframe as index

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have the following lists: `brands_list = {"b1": {"name": "brand1"}, "b2". {"name": "brand2"}}` and `actual_brands = ["brand1"]`, and a Pandas dataframe with a column `brand` with the following content: `"b1", "b1", "b1", "b2", "b1"`, and I want to assign a value to column `is_brand_present` if the element of `brands_list` with index of column `brand` is in `actual_brands`.

I try the following using numpy's `where`:

```
brands_list = {"b1": "brand1", "b2". "brand2"}
actual_brands = ["brand1"]

data_frame["is_brand_present"] = np.where(
    brands_list[data_frame["brand"]].isin(actual_brands), 1, 0
)
```

I expect the content of column `is_brand_present` to be `1,1,1,0,1`, but I'm getting this error:

```
TypeError: unhashable type: 'Series'
```

How can I make the evaluation of the condition?

Comment: Could you provide the actual data types of the variables? list (`brands_list`) has no attribute `.isin`, and you are calling a dictionary a list

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can just do

```
l = [x for x, y in brands_list.items() if y['name'] in actual_brands ]


df['is_brand_present'] = df.brand.isin(l).astype(int)
```

Answer (score 3):

IIUC , you are looking for (map 'brand' column to dictionary and check if its in actual brands)

```
df['is_brand_present'] = df['brand'].map(brands_list).isin(actual_brands).astype(int)
```

If your brands_list is nested as per your update to question, you can use:

```
df['brand'].map({k: v['name']
                 for k, v in brands_list.items()
                 }).isin(actual_brands).astype(int)
```

print(df):

```
  brand  is_brand_present
0    b1                 1
1    b1                 1
2    b1                 1
3    b2                 0
4    b1                 1
```

Comment: I missed something in `brands_list`, it is a nested dict. Your answer is perfect but I can't figure out how to adapt it to a nested dict. Could you review your answer, please.